# how to make app.use synchronous in nodejs

Tags: node.js, express, asynchronous

I have created a nodejs app with the express framework. There are some routes and I am using passport library for authentication. Here is my login url mapping

```
app.post('/login', loginHandler);
```

and before this, I have used `app.use`

```
// middleware to use passport strategy
app.use((req: any, res: any, next: any) => {
   if (req.originalUrl == '/login') {
       passport.authenticate('local', { session: false }, (err, user) => {
             if (user) {
                req.user = user;
             }
       })(req, res, next);
   }
   next();
});
```

and in my `loginHandler`

```
function loginHandler(req: any, res: any) {
    console.log("user", req.user)
    if (!req.user) {
       console.log("NoUser")
    } else {
        res.redirect("/home");
}
```

but `loginHandler` method does not get user object in request object because `app.use` is asynchronous. How can I solve this?

Comment: Mark it if that solve your issue . I have added else condition too.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As from the @Himanshu's answer, I need to use `next()` method inside the passports authenticate callback function. This works but for other requests, there still need a `next()` function. So the updated answer is

```
// middleware to use passport strategy
app.use((req: any, res: any, next: any) => {
   if (req.originalUrl == '/login') {
       passport.authenticate('local', { session: false }, (err, user) => {
             if (user) {
                req.user = user;
             }
             next();
       })(req, res, next);
   } else { 
       next();
   }

});
```

Answer (score 1):

Edit your code and make this change .

```
// middleware to use passport strategy
app.use((req: any, res: any, next: any) => {
   if (req.originalUrl == '/login') {
       passport.authenticate('local', { session: false }, (err, user) => {
             if (user) {
                req.user = user;
             }
               next();         ////// change is here
       })(req, res, next);
   }else{
     next();
   }

});
```

The code is correct but you call `next()` synchronous way . Add `next()` inside the passport block will allow you to pass the `req.user` perfectly